# VBSCRIPT REPLACE not removing spaces from Decrypted fields

Tags: sql-server, encryption, replace, vbscript, spaces

Got quite a head-scratcher....

I'm using the VBScript function REPLACE to replace spaces in a decrypted field from a MSSQL DB with "/".

But the REPLACE function isn't "seeing" the spaces.

For example, if I run any one of the following, where the decrypted value of the field "ITF_U_ClientName_Denc" is "Johnny Carson":

```
REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc")," ","/")
REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),"&nbsp;","/")
REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),"Chr(160)","/")
REPLACE(CSTR(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"))," ","/")
REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc")," ","/",1,-1,1)
REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc")," ","/",1,-1,0)
```

The returned value is "Johnny Carson" (space not replaced with /)

The issue seems to be exclusively with spaces, because when I run this: 
    REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),"a","/")

I get "Johnny C/rson".

Also, the issue seems to be exclusively with spaces in the decrypted value, because when I run this:

```
REPLACE("Johnny Carson"," ","/")
```

Of course, the returned value is "Johnny/Carson".

I have checked what is being written to the source of the page and it is simply "Johnny Carson" with no encoding or special characters.

I have also tried the SPLIT function to see if it would "see" the space, but it doesn't.

Finally, thanks to a helpful comment, I tried VBS REGEX searching for \s.

```
Set regExp = New RegExp
regExp.IgnoreCase = True
regExp.Global = True
regExp.Pattern = "\s" 'Add here every character you don't consider as special character
strProcessed = regExp.Replace(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"), "?")
```

Unfortunately, strProcessed retruns "Johnny Carson" (ie. spaces not detected/removed).

If I replace regExp.Pattern = "a", strProcessed returns "Johnny C?rson".

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: it might be due to encoding, did you try regular expressions? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853070/replace-special-characters-in-vbscript `\s` is for whitespace, `\S` is for non-whitespace.

Comment: Not REGEX but I tried REPLACE with every variant of space listed in the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515365/are-there-other-whitespace-codes-like-nbsp-for-half-spaces-em-spaces-en-space. I'll try the REGEX approach to see it it "sees" the decrypted space.

Comment: Just tried with REGEX but it doesn't "see" the space either (see updates to question).

Comment: hm. so you're saying `asc(mid(thatstring,7,1))` returns 32 (which is for space)?

Comment: Response.Write(asc(mid("Johnny Carson",7,1))) returns 32 but Response.Write(asc(mid(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),7,1))) returns 15712 (&#87826; Invalid Character). Still, REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),"&#87826;","/",1,-1,1) returns "Johnny Carson" (ie. no &#87826; found).

Comment: More info... this site (https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer#e=Sm9obm55IENhcnNvbg) parses the space in ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc") ("Johnny Carson") as U+0020 but when I try REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),"&#32;","/"), I still get "Johnny Carson" (ie. it doesn't see the &#32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found, the right character code is 160, and that did the trick:

```
replace(..., ChrW(160), "...")
```

This seems to be data specific and, additionally, as an alternative you can try to get same encoding of the source script (i.e. save with *Save As with Encoding*), or convert received database value into a different target encoding.

Comment: Actually the character shown by ASC() is -15712 but REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),ChrW(-15712),"/"), REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),ChrW(15712),"/") and REPLACE(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc")," ","/") all display "Johnny Carson" (ie. no space found) :(

Comment: if trying AscW which is for double-byte character set i.e. `Response.Write(AscW(mid(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"),7,1)))` do you see same -15712? Also did you try to assign db value to a local string variable, i.e. `s = ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc")` and then replace?

Comment: Y, I assigned the field to a variable before trying to replay and also tried strFullName = CSTR(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"). 

When I run the AscW version, I get 160. Is that a clue?

Comment: 160 stands for &nbsp; / non-breaking space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space i.e. it looks like this is not UTF or ASCII but ANSI. Please try `replace("...", ChrW(160), "...")`

Comment: That was it! 
strFullName = CSTR(ITF_U_Ledger.Fields("ITF_U_ClientName_Denc"))
strFullName = REPLACE(strFullName,ChrW(160),"/")
produces "Johnny/Carson". Want to rework this as the answer and I'll give you credit for the solution?

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Marked your answer correct,. Be well and stay healthy!